# Defining an extension for both the Swift and Objective-C classes

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I am trying to migrate my application to swift from Objective C.
I was having couple of Objective C categories. Since Swift is having "Extensions", I have created it. But some how , I am not able to call it from existing Objective C.

Below code gives compilation error

```
No visible @interface for 'NSString' declares the selector 'myCategory'
```

Extension class

```
import Foundation


     extension String {

        func myCategory() -> String {

            return "I am From Swift";

        }


    }
```

My ViewController

```
#import <TestProject-Swift.h>


@interface TestViewController ()

@end

@implementation TestViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    NSString *str = @"Testing";

    NSLog(@"Here is result %@", [str myCategory]);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

And how it will be work with Swift class also?
I have created Bridging header file also for above extension file.

EDIT:
I have tried making "public" but its not working.

Comment: I have already tried but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the right idea, but Swift's `String` and Cocoa's `NSString` are two different types. The reason you aren't aware of this is that thanks to some magic, Swift is happy to call `NSString` methods on `String` to make your life easier. Make your extension on `NSString` instead of `String` and it should work in both contexts.